# Is there a way to prevent On-demand VPN from being turnned off?

Tags: ios, vpn, ondemand

I want to create a VPN configuration profile and enable the use of the On-demand feature. My main goal is to always keep the VPN on, that every connection will go out through the VPN tunnel.

I'm looking for a (programmatic preferred) way to prevent a user from disabling the On-demand feature.
The trick is - I can't use an MDM profile in no way.

Is there anyone here that is familiar with a way to prevent from a user from  turning off the On-demand option? No MDM usage?

Thank you

Comment: what hardware, software, OS are you using?

Comment: I want to install the profile on ios 7 and 8 on iphone devices

Comment: Why do you prefer a programmatic way, and why can't you use a profile (the simplest and most obvious way to solve your problem)

Comment: I can use a profile, just not an MDM profile

Answer (score 2):

If the user connects via your app why dont you check for a connected state and call

```
 self.targetManager.onDemandEnabled = true;
        self.targetManager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ (NSError) -> Void in
        })
```

This way it will save on demand as a preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to the phone before giving it to the user, and make it supervised, then yes.

From Apple's deployment guide:

Always-on VPN
Overview
Always-on VPN gives your organization full control over device traffic by tunneling all IP traffic back to the organization. The default tunneling protocol, IKEv2, secures traffic transmission with data encryption. Your organizations can now monitor and filter traffic to and from its devices, secure data within its network, and restrict device access to the Internet.
Always-on VPN activation requires device supervision. Once the Always-on VPN profile is installed on a device, Always-on VPN automatically activates with no user interaction. Always-on VPN stays activated (including across reboots) until the Always-on VPN profile is uninstalled.

Comment: When utilizing a VPN and toggling on the "Always ON" option, if you just download  a separate VPN from the app store an activate it, the old VPN is overwritten and it begins to run that new VPN.  Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: @dgelinas21There is a key in the restrictions payload that might be useful to you. 

`allowVPNCreation`, Boolean, Supervised only. If set to false, disallow the creation of VPN configurations. Defaults to true. Availability: Available only in iOS 11.0 and later.

Please note that un-toggling the Connect On Demand toggle of most VPNs is enough to disable it. You must use the AlwaysOn VPN type with the associated AlwaysOn dictionary keys to prevent disabling of the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
let targetManager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
targetManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true;
targetManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (NSError) -> Void in

})
```